# How to convert array<string> to string in hive

Tags: arrays, string, hive, hiveql

I want to convert an `array<string>` to string in hive. The array data is as follow:

```
+-------------------------------------+--+
| NULL                                |
| ["Extension","Terms & Conditions"]  |
| ["Value (generic or item level)"]   |
+-------------------------------------+--+
```

I want to collect array values to convert to string without `[""]` so that I could get result like:

```
+-------------------------------------+--+
| NULL                                |
| Extension,Terms & Conditions        |
| Value (generic or item level)       |
+-------------------------------------+--+
```

Following query: `select concat_ws(',', col_name) as col_name from table_stg;` provides the result but is is returning `NULL` as empty. I tried several reference like:

[How can I convert array to string in hive sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711201/how-can-i-convert-array-to-string-in-hive-sql)

[Hive - How to cast array to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483400/hive-how-to-cast-array-to-string)

But not getting the desired result. Is there any way to get the desired result?

Comment: use a `case` expression. `case when size(col_name) = 0 then null else concat_ws(',',col_name) end`

Comment: Hi @VamsiPrabhala - checking size doesn't worked, but it gave me the idea to solve this. thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

With reference to Vamsi comment, I managed to get this and thought to answer as well for the community reference.

```
select case when col_name is NULL then NULL 
    else concat_ws(',',col_name) end from table_name;
```